# Matrix Reps of Associative algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

It is widely known that non-associative algebras do not possess matrix reps as matrix multiplication is associative. Is the converse true? I.e. do all associative algebras has a faithful matrix rep?

Comment: Of course if $B$ is associative and $A$ isn't then there's no injective algebra homomorphism $A \to B$. But nonassociative algebras may come with their own notion of matrix rep, e.g. [Ado's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado's_theorem) is a result guaranteeing faithful reps of finite-dimensional Lie algebras over fields of characteristic zero.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an associative algebra over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and you want a ($\mathbb{K}$-linear) faithful matrix representation in $M_n(\mathbb{K})$ for some $n$, then this is clearly not possible if $A$ is infinite-dimensional. And if $A$ is finite-dimensional, there always is such a representation: the action of $A$ on itself by multiplication gives a representation in $M_d(\mathbb{K})$ for $d=\dim_{\mathbb{K}}(A)$ (the regular representation).

Comment: So even non-associative algebras have matrix reps?

Comment: @Benjamin Sorry, I meant associative algebra: I'll edit.

Comment: Ok, I suspected...